# Making a formula for etching a ring

Tags: geometry, projection

I am looking for some help creating a simple formula to help etch Wedding Rings.

**The Setup**

I have a Laser firing from a central point 280mm above the surface. The beam is directed in X,Y axis to plot the design.

[image]

I have a wedding ring, in this example 20mm diameter and 8mm wide, a flattened torus shape. Siting on the base at a 45deg angle.

[image]

**The Area to be etched**

From the lasers view looking at the ring, the ring will look like an ellipse 20mm x 14mm, and I would like to etch the inside area.

[image]

**Problem**

I need to Calculate this surface as a 2d area, My only requirement is the sides of the shape. I need to know the Curve, and Trapezoidal correction.
This example shows a ring with a flat surface though this can be closer to a torus, some rings are flat some torus.

**In Software**

I will draw my intended shape, I am looking how to create 2 formulas, one to find the amount I squish the circle by, so in this case 14mm.

The second formula is adjusting the sides, the trapezoid sides. This coorects the blur from the ring being on an angle as well as the amount from being flat on the inside to being a complete torus.
If this example was a torus it would have curves on the sides, not straight.

[image]

**Final Requirements**

Input:

- Inner Ring Diameter
- Ring Width

Output

- Ring Width X Ring Height
- Amount to adjust Trapezoid

Let me know if you need anymore information to clarify objective.

Thank you for your help.

I had created ths question earlier which may have more context to help fully understand the question. I apologise for the multiple questions.

[First Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3809942/project-shape-of-a-ring-to-a-plane/3810036#3810036)

[Second Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3811388/how-to-make-a-formula-for-etching-rings)

**Finished Item**

This is a finished item and how it ends up looking on the ring. For reference.

[image: final etched ring]

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! This appears to be your third attempt at this question, the others ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3811388/409) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3809942/409)) having been closed for lack of context. Reposting a question is not really the way to clarify it or bring more attention to it; rather, you should edit the previous version(s) to improve its quality. (Multiple posts of a question just cause confusion.) In any case, you should add links back from this question to your earlier ones, as those seem to have clarifying comments that some may find useful.

Comment: Ahh ok, I tried to edit the first one but thought if it was closed I didn't know how to reopen it. Thank you

Comment: How do you parameterize the "trapezoidial correction"?

Comment: @user619894 any way is fine. If it’s a measurement of extending top and bottom lengths I would use a box to snap the nodes to it. If it’s by an angle I can make a line and set to that angle.

Comment: Just a thought - there is a [3D printing stack exchange](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/) for which this question might be better suited.

Comment: @K.defaoite Yes my question is more about how to project a 2d design onto a 3D shape so possibly 3D Printing SE could be suitable. I was just thinking to ask here to hopefully find someone who can think of a mathematical solution.

Comment: @Tim You should edit your original question (by updating it) instead of asking a new question, following the guidelines in [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Then if 5 high-rep users vote to reopen your question, your question will be reopened.